# How make Swagger-UI work in a Play application

Tags: playframework, swagger, swagger-ui

I've just integrated Swagger into my Play application and it works – `http://localhost:9000/api-docs/` returns the api doc in JSON format.

Now I'd like to use Swagger-UI... and I've copied the [distro](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-ui/tree/master/dist) to `myApp\public` as suggested in the README file, but no way to make it work – the documentation seems to be a bit outdated.

I've tried to add this to `conf\routes`...

```
GET  /swagger-ui    staticDir:public/swagger-ui
```

... but it doesn't work and I always get the following error message:

```
Controller method call expected
```

The content of directory `public/swagger` is [here](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-ui/tree/master/dist).
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just added the following route to file `routes`:

```
GET /swagger-ui/*file  controllers.Assets.at(path = "/public/swagger-ui", file)
```

I hope it helps.